# IntelliJ reporting typescript error for react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using react-bootstrap-table-next (aka react-bootstrap-table2). I'm getting a Typescript error in IntelliJ on the validator field in my column definition. I can't seem to get around it in IntelliJ although it works OK in the sandbox. Even putting `//@ts-ignore` on it doesn't help

Here's my column definition:

```
    const columns: ColumnDescription[] = [
        {
            dataField: 'id',
            text: 'Product ID',
            headerStyle: () => {
                return { width: '20%', textAlign: 'center' };
            }
        },
        {
            dataField: 'name',
            text: 'Product Name',
            sort: true,
            headerStyle: () => {
                return { width: '60%', textAlign: 'center' };
            }
        },
        {
            dataField: 'value',
            text: 'Product value',
            sort: true,
            validator: (newValue, row, column) => {
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    return {
                        valid: false,
                        message: 'This field needs to be a number'
                    };
                }
            },
            headerStyle: () => {
                return { width: '20%', textAlign: 'center' };
            }
        }];
```

[image]

Sandbox is here, where it seems to work
https://codesandbox.io/s/table-validator-7ib2n

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiler error, you will see the same error when running `tsc` in command line. The error is also shown in sandbox:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work in the sandbox but not in IntelliJ. Maybe it's just a warning in the sandbox. But if it's a compiler error, how do I fix it? Do I need to specify the correct type?

Comment: it's a compiler error in both the sandbox and IDEA; you need changing the method signature to get rid of the error

Comment: Well, again, that's exactly what I'm asking help for.  I couldn't figure out what the signature needs to be.  Despite the error, the code seems to run in the Sandbox, but I can't get it to run in IntelliJ